# .htaccess - How to Override Url Even If someone Puts the .PHP after the filename

Tags: .htaccess

I have created the .htaccess file to rewrite url for .php

Before creating the .htaccess files

Url was like : www.xyz.com/contact.php

After creating the file

Its like : www.xyz.com/contact

But if someone writes in the url

www.xyz.com/contact.php

The .PHP extension is displayed hoe to hide it even if someone enters it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code will remove .php even if users write it :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks Worked For Me Perfectly :D

Comment: i have a .php file with deploy_email.php, how to enable extension only for this file in .htaccess as this file is beign called through ajax so its failing to get the contents because due to the code it is now only deploy_email